# How to output multiple lists while looping through other input lists?

Tags: python, list

For the following 2 input lists, I want different output lists based on the first one:

```
al = ["tr1", "tr2", "tr3"]
bl = ["tile1", "tile2", "tile3"]
newlist  = []

for a in al:
    for b in bl:
        c = a+b+"5"
        newlist.append(c)
print(newlist)

['tr1tile15', 'tr1tile25', 'tr1tile35', 'tr2tile15', 'tr2tile25', 'tr2tile35', 'tr3tile15', 'tr3tile25', 'tr3tile35']
```

Desired output:

```
newlist_tr1 = ['tr1tile15', 'tr1tile25', 'tr1tile35']
newlist_tr2 = ['tr2tile15', 'tr2tile25', 'tr2tile35']
newlist_tr3 = ['tr3tile15', 'tr3tile25', 'tr3tile35']
```

Working on Windows 10, Python 3.7.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an intermediate list in the loop

```
al = ["tr1", "tr2", "tr3"]
bl = ["tile1", "tile2", "tile3"]
newlist = []

for a in al:
    tmp = []
    for b in bl:
        tmp.append(a + b + "5")
    newlist.append(tmp)

print(newlist) 
# [['tr1tile15', 'tr1tile25', 'tr1tile35'], 
   ['tr2tile15', 'tr2tile25', 'tr2tile35'], 
   ['tr3tile15', 'tr3tile25', 'tr3tile35']]
```

---

You can achieve the same with [`lists-comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
newlist = [[a + b + "5" for b in bl] for a in al]
```

Comment: thank you very much!!!!! How is that called? I checked in python tutorials about lists, but I couldn't find information on how to build those lists. Also, you are creating a list of lists, I guess, making complete independent lists is different

Comment: @delViento this is called `list-comprehension` https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions . Also you can now think about acepting the answer, green tick, if it satisfies you ;)

Comment: Thank you! I upvoted it and forgot to accept

Answer (score 0):

```
al = ["tr1", "tr2", "tr3"]
bl = ["tile1", "tile2", "tile3"]

newlist = [[a + b + "5" for b in bl] for a in al]
```

Result:

```
[['tr1tile15', 'tr1tile25', 'tr1tile35'],
 ['tr2tile15', 'tr2tile25', 'tr2tile35'],
 ['tr3tile15', 'tr3tile25', 'tr3tile35']]
```

Answer (score 0):

````
bl = ["tile1", "tile2", "tile3"]
newlist  = []


for a in al:
    for b in bl:
        c = a+b+"5"
        newlist.append(c)
    print(newlist)
    newlist  = []

['tr1tile15', 'tr1tile25', 'tr1tile35']
['tr2tile15', 'tr2tile25', 'tr2tile35']
['tr3tile15', 'tr3tile25', 'tr3tile35']```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

m=["".join(elem)+'5' for elem in list(product(al,bl))]

for i in al:
    newlist_i =m[:len(al)]
```

[product(A, B)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) `returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.